# To call Javascript Function from dynmaically created Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code i have a dynamically created textbox and on onfocus event i am calling a javascript function .And i am assign onfocus event values on page load .And it is not working after creating onfocus event.Pls help me to solve the issue.
Test1,Test2 values are assigned on pageload

```
function createFields(Test1,Test2) {
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     if (type == "TextBox") {
         newdiv.innerHTML += 
            "<input class=\"form-control\" data-error=\"Please Provide " 
            + DisplayName 
            + "\" name=\"" 
            + Name 
            + "\" value=\"" 
            + FieldValue 
            + "\" onFocus=\"" 
            + HighlightField(Test1,Test2) 
            + "\"  id=\"" 
            + Name + "\"/>";
        $('#divComplete').append(newdiv);
    }
}

    function HighlightField(Test1,Test2) {

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the code? It does not seem clear what the newdiv object is. Perhaps include the part of the code where you create newdiv.

Comment: Try: `$('body').on('focus','.form-control[type="text"]',function(){//your code here})`

Answer (score 0):

> on onfocus event i am calling a javascript function

No you're not.  Look closely at what's happening here:

```
"onFocus=\"" + HighlightField(Test1,Test2) + "\"
```

You're calling `HighlightField()` *immediately* and setting its *result* to the `onFocus` handler.

Unless that function actually returns a string of valid JavaScript code, it's likely that your resulting HTML looks like this:

```
onFocus=""
```

If you want to call the function in the `onFocus` event, don't invoke it.  Instead, just specify the function call in the string you're creating:

```
"onFocus=\"HighlightField(Test1,Test2)\""
```

**Edit:** Given the clarification on your question, it sounds like you want those variables to be interpreted right away.  But *not* the function call itself.  That would be done the same way it's done anywhere else in that string.  Something like this:

```
"onFocus=\"HighlightField(" + Test1 + "," + Test2 + ")\""
```

Note that if those variables are expected to contain *string data* then you'd also need to add *quotes* (since strings need to be quoted):

```
"onFocus=\"HighlightField('" + Test1 + "','" + Test2 + "')\""
```

As you're probably starting to notice, dynamically building code like this is a bit unwieldy.  Since you're using jQuery anyway, at the very least you should remove the in-line event handler and create a separate event handler elsewhere in the code.  Something like:

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input.form-control', function () {
    // handle your focus event here
});
```

Then you wouldn't need to build this complex string.

Comment: Test1 and test 2 are variables you are created as string how to pass as variavle

Comment: @Dotnet: That depends.  Do you need them to be interpreted immediately while building this string, or do you need them to be interpreted dynamically when the event is invoked?  The code you've provided isn't clear on that.

Comment: @Dotnet: In that case you'd need to remove those values from the string and interpret them as variables.  *Exactly* as you do it in several other places throughout the string.  See my updated answer.